# Postman request chaining

Tags: javascript, postman, newman

I want to have postman tests running on my CI environment. Now, before I make a call to an endpoint, I need to make a call to one of our oauth endpoints, to ensure I have access token. On postman there is 2 year old [ticket](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/697) with a ton of upvotes and suggestions to use [setNextRequest](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/workflows) in pre-request (which is supported from postman 4.5, apparently). Thus, I had the following in my pre-request section:

```
var responseBody = postman.setNextRequest("/oauth/token");
```

It did not work, it seems the "/oauth/token" never even been called (didn't show up in the postman console). I am sure I'm not the first person bangin my head against this scenario, so my question - is there a way to call an item from the collection (the one that gives me access token) ? That is, I do not want to have the same oauth request duplicated before every test requiring said access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see you are using `responseBody` in pre-request section. Although you are just trying to set it to next request. `responseBody` is not available in there. `responseBody` is available in `Tests` section only (obviously due to the request already been executed).

Regarding your scenario, why don't you follow:

1. Execute your auth request as the first call
2. Get the access token
3. Store it in an environment variable
4. Use the token in subsequent requests where you need it.

This will make sure all your request have access token generated on run time.

Comment: yes, so this is my default strategy. I though maybe there is a more elegant way to do it, like somehow executing a request from another collection would give me more flexibility on how to structure my tests.

Comment: Currently `postman.setNextRequest` method only looks for requests in the same collection.

Answer (score 2):

postman.setNextRequest() is for executing a desired request after current request. This wont solve your problem. Best is store it in a environment variable using 
postman.setEnvironmentVariable() function and call where ever required.

Comment: yes, so this was my gut feeling as well. But why do the postman people say that setNextRequest is supported for the pre-request? What would be a use case here?